# Socket import sending variables help (Python)

Tags: python, sockets, import, thonny

So I have been working on a chat room client, except I have one problem. I have been wanting to be able to list who is online and the easiest way I would do that would be with variables. I would have a starting variable that would be for example:

OnlineClients = []

Which other clients when they join I want their client to send the variable 'OnlineClients.append(name)' to add it to the list. When they quit it should also send the command 'OnlineClients.remove(name)'. Is there any way I can do this?

This is a snippet of my code of my attempts to send variables:

```
#This list is important because it is used for listing who is on the chat
OnlineClients = ["Person1", "Person2", "Person3"]
ListOnline = (" ".join(OnlineClients))

#THIS IS TEST 1 FOR VARIABLE SENDING
#In future update remove own name from online list
#!to_varlist = (OnlineClients.append(name))
s.send(OnlineClients.append("Apple").encode())

#to_send = (person1 = name)
#s.send(to_send.encode())

#to_var = a = b
#s.send(to_var.encode())

#s.send(a=b.encode())
```

Comment: create classes and functions for handling data conversion and sending (and every other part of your program). this is not how you write a program. if you had a class for converting a list to bytestrings and sending it over socket, you could simply call that whenever you want to update someone about list of online people..

Comment: I have tried that but it manages to freeze the server, I could try to send it without printing it out on the other system and have each command send as a string of random numbers to not mix in with what people are typing.